# A Single Column Form Layout

Tags: html, css, django

I'm trying to display a django form in a single column in stead of in the default two-column display.

[not like this...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PiRrn.jpg)

[...but rather like this!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4kQI.jpg)

I've been looking through some videos and posts, and found only methods like using crispy-forms and the like, but it strikes me, that that's an awful lot of lines of code to add for achieving such a tiny goal. - Might there be a simpler sollution perhaps (otherwise, which is the best method)? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just render your form fields manually and you can put the **labels** anywhere you want.

For example...

```
<div class="fieldWrapper">
    {{ form.subject.errors }}
    <div class="labelWrapper"><label for="{{ form.subject.id_for_label }}">Email subject:</label></div>
    {{ form.subject }}
</div>
```

...where subject is your form field.

Check a great Django blog post even with similar Bootstrap 4 example you want at [Simple is better than complex](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/article/2017/08/19/how-to-render-django-form-manually.html).